# What does this number beside "reopen" option means?

Tags: discussion

What does this mean? That just one user has voted to reopen that question or that just one more vote is needed to reopen it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's like the "close" button. It means that one person has voted to reopen it/close it.